# Select an image from JPanel

Tags: java

I am working on a small project which requires me to load images into a window and then move them around at will.

Thus far I can load images onto a JPanel simply by using a graphics object to draw them to the JPanel.

Now I'm faced with the challenge of figuring out how to differentiate between the various images I've loaded when I click on them so I can drag them around the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could subclass `JPanel` and make the image a member variable, and then you could query the selected `JPanel` for its image object to do the differentiating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `JLabel` for each image, and make the `JLabels` subcomponents of the `JPanel`, it'll automatically draw the image, and you can add [`MouseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)s to each of them to be able to drag them around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) to drag any component around the screen.